# Can SSD Storage from 2016 Macbook Pro be moved to 2019 Macbook Pro?

Tags: hard-drive, mac, ssd, macbook, macbook-pro

I have MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports) with 1TB drive.

I would like to buy one of the new 2019 Macbook Pros with 256GB and swap the storage. I have seen the video on the 2016 SSD removal but can't find info if the 2019 is using the same type of a drive thus I can swap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have seen the video on the 2016 SSD removal but can't find info if the 2019 is using the same type of a drive thus I can swap.

The 2019 MacBook Pro SSD is soldered to the motherboard.

Comment: [iFixIt](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Two+Thunderbolt+Ports+2019+Teardown/124676) has instructions.  Why do you need images of an SSD that is soldered to the motherboard and incompatible with the 2016 MacBook Pro SSD?  An image of the soldered proprietary SSD chip wouldn’t be useful in answering your question